# Loop through HTML table in custom order using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I have a HTML table. Some of the cells have #D6FFAD/rgb(214, 255, 173) as their background. I need to create a function that loops through the table and changes only cells with that background, to a different color. The interval needs to be consistent. It needs to go through the table cells in a particular order. This order is shown by their IDs (t1 - t10).

The below loops through and changes colours as needed. The consistency of the intervals is a problem though. For example, #T1 - #T4 all need their backgrounds changing, the interval is fine until here. There is then a delay whilst it looks at #T5 and #T6 before changing the color of #T7. I really need to skip 5 and 6 but struggling to think of a solution.

Can I put an IF statement for the second parameter of the setInterval()? Perhaps something like IF no background, set interval to 0 otherwise, 300?

CSS:

```
.changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction{background:#D6FFAD}
```

JS:

```
i=1; 
setInterval(

function(){
t = document.getElementById('t'+i);
ts = window.getComputedStyle(t);
        if(ts.backgroundColor=='rgb(214, 255, 173)'){t.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';}
        i=i+1;

    if(i>=25){
        i=1;
        x = $("#selectDropdown option:selected").val();
        $('.'+x).css("background","#D6FFAD");
              }
       }    

 ,300);
```

HTML

```
<tr id="rowOne">
<td id="t1" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">blah</td>  
<td id="t3" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">blah</td>
<td id="t5">blah</td>
<td id="t7" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">blah</td>
<td id="t9">blah</td>
<td id="t10" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">blah</td>
</tr>

<tr id="rowTwo">
<td id="t2" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">blah</td>  
<td id="t4" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">Blah</td>
<td id="t6">Blah</td>
<td id="t8">blah</td>
<td id="t10" class="changeThisBackgroundWithIntervalFunction">Blah</td>
<td id="t12">Blah</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the behavior of the selectDropdown? Should it reset the color of all table cells and restart the animation?

Comment: The above is a simplified version. Cells can have numerous classes. Eg. <td id="t1" class="classOne classTwo classThree">blah</td>

Comment: $('#selectDropdown').change(function() {
  x=$(this).val();
  $('td').css("background","white");
  $('.'+x).css("background","#D6FFAD");

Comment: setInterval function here

Comment: }); So yes, it resets colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first define which elements that need to be updated, put them in an array and then after each timeout, update the next element in that array.

```
var i;

var cellsToUpdate = [];
for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById('t' + i);
    if (window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor == 'rgb(214, 255, 173)')
        cellsToUpdate.push(element);
}

i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(
function () {
    if (i >= cellsToUpdate.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    cellsToUpdate[i].style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    i++;
}

, 300);
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9S9Gw/). Call the code above after you have changed the colors with the select dropdown. Don't forget to clear the interval when it is done.

Comment: perfect. Much appreciated!